# Convert a comma separated string to int PHP?

Tags: php, string, int

Is there any way you can convert "185,345,321" to 185345321 by using PHP?

Comment: By removing the commas?

Comment: This is a good question. If you try to convert "1,096" using (int) or intval, the result will be 1.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$str = "185,345,321";
$newStr = str_replace(',', '', $str); // If you want it to be "185345321"
$num = intval($newStr); // If you want it to be a number 185345321
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by-

```
$intV = intval(str_replace(",","","185,345,321"));
```

Here `intval()` is used to convert `string` to `integer`.

Answer (score 5):

You can get rid of the commas by doing

```
$newString = str_replace(",", "", $integerString);
```

then

```
$myNewInt = intval($newString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Example:

```
str_replace( ",", "", "123,456,789");
```

Live example: 
http://ideone.com/Q7IAIN

Answer (score 4):

```
$string= "185,345,321";
echo str_replace(",","",$string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string replacement, `str_replace` or `preg_replace` are viable solutions.

```
$string = str_replace(",","","185,345,321");
```

PHP *should* take care of type casting after that so you deal with an integer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "185,345,321";
$newstr = str_replace(',','',$str);
echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace(",","","185,345,321")
```

[str_replace tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)